# Frobenius Norm Equivalence

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I am trying to show that:

$$
|| A||_{F} \leq \sqrt{r} \cdot ||A||_{2} 
$$

where $A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix and $r$ is its rank. My attempt is to use Cauchy-Swcharz inequality to show this:

I let $e = \{ e_1, ..., e_n \}$ is the basis.

$$
||A ||_{F}^{2} = \sum_{i}^{n} || a_{i} ||_{2}^{2} = \sum_i ||A e_i||_{2}^{2} \leq \sum_i ||A||_{2}^{2} ||e_i||_{2}^{2} = ||A||_{2}^{2} \cdot \sum_i ||e_{i}||_{2}^{2} = n \times ||A||_{2}^{2} 
$$

How do I improve this bound to have the inequalithy that $||A||_F \leq \sqrt{r} ||A||_2$?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we work over the real numbers, note that the singular values of $A$ are defined by $\sigma_i^2(A)=\lambda_i(A^{\mathsf{T}}A)$, with $\|A\|_2=\sigma_1(A)$ (the largest singular value). Moreover the trace operator satisfies, $\mathrm{Tr}(A)=\sum^n_{i=1}\lambda_i(A)$. So, if $A$ is of rank $r$, then we know that $\|A\|_F^2=\mathrm{Tr}(A^{\mathsf{T}}A)=\sum^r_{i=1}\sigma^2_i(A)\leq r \|A\|_2^2$. The crux is that just $r$ singular values are non-zero (consider the SVD of $A$).